# How am I supposed to use prepared statements in Wordpress with variables in a query?

Tags: php, wordpress, prepared-statement

I'm currently learning Wordpress and PHP, I'm also using WooCommerce. I currently have a form with three input fields, and I would like to check if the user inputted data about their order is true so the user can proceed to the next page.

My current code looks like this, and I am not sure if I am even going the right direction here, any help?

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
global $wpdb;

$ordernumber = $_POST['ordernmbr'];
$orderfirstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$orderpostnumber = $_POST['postnmbr'];

$ordernumber = stripslashes_deep($ordernumber);
$orderfirstname = stripslashes_deep($orderfirstname);
$orderpostnumber = stripslashes_deep($orderpostnumber);


$result = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM         $wpdb->wp_postmeta
  WHERE post_id = '$ordernumber' AND meta_value = '$orderfirstname'"));
```

Comment: There is only any point is preparing a query if it has parameters that you will replace on the execute. You are concatenating values, which is very unsafe [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it using prepare:

```
$sql = 'DELETE FROM `wp_table` WHERE `id_field` = %d';
$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare($sql, array($_POST['id']))
```

Good things to know:

```
%d - number
%s - string
%f - float
```

the array of passed variables works in sequential order, so if you had a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_table` WHERE `string_field` = %s AND `id_field` = %d
```

you'd do

```
array(
    $_POST['string'],
    $_POST['id']
)
```

if it's a DELETE/UPDATE use query and prepare. If a select use prepare and get_results.

SELECT:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `wp_table` WHERE `id` = %d';
$sql = $wpdb->prepare($sql, array($_POST['id']));
$res = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

Comment: In the select statement at the end, if I have stored the $_POST data in to variables, could I use those instead in the array without it causing any problems later on?

Comment: @Puppe yeah, the $_POST was just for examples sake :)

Comment: Just making sure since I'm super new, thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

It's best practice to always use `prepare` but the main use of it is to prevent against SQL injection attacks, and since there is no input from the users/visitors or they can't effect the query then that is not an issue in your current example.

But like I said before it's best practice to use it and once you start using it you never stop, so in your example you can use it like so:

```
global $wpdb;
$tablename = $wpdb->prefix . "my_custom_table";
$sql = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM %s ORDER BY date_created DESC",$tablename );
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $sql , ARRAY_A );
```

to read more about how to use it head to the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add your query conditional values as prepare function parameters. like the below statement

```
$wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta WHERE post_id = %d AND meta_value = %s", $ordernumber, $orderfirstname);
```

for string values we use %s

for numeric values we use %d